# Insertar multiples productos array for PHP

Tags: php, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario que envie multiples clientes y que cada cliente pueda seleccionar productos via checkbox.
Formulario HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="505" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><strong>CLIENTE 01</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="71">Nombre</td>
      <td colspan="4">
      <input type="text" name="nombres[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellidos</td>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="apellidos[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Productos</td>
      <td width="99"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H1">
      H1</td>
      <td width="83"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H2">
      <label for="checkbox">H2 </label></td>
      <td width="98"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H3">
      <label for="checkbox">H3 </label></td>
      <td width="120"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H4">
      <label for="checkbox">H4 </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><strong>CLIENTE 02</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="71">Nombre</td>
      <td colspan="4">
      <input type="text" name="nombres[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellidos</td>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="apellidos[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Productos</td>
      <td width="99"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H1">
      H1</td>
      <td width="83"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H2">
      <label for="checkbox">H2 </label></td>
      <td width="98"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H3">
      <label for="checkbox">H3 </label></td>
      <td width="120"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="H4">
      <label for="checkbox">H4 </label></td>
    </tr>  
      <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><button>Enviar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Codigo PHP que envia el formulario a la base de datos, estoy usando el ciclo for pero no guarda los checkbox seleccionados por el usuario

```
$userData = count($_POST["nombres"]);
if ($userData > 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $userData; $i++) {
        $clientes = trim($_POST['nombres'][$i]); 
        if (!empty($clientes)){
        $nombres  = $_POST["nombres"][$i];
        $apellidos  = $_POST["apellidos"][$i];

        $pro = implode(",",$_POST['pro']);  
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO ventas (nombres, apellidos, pro) VALUES ( :nombres, :apellidos, :pro)";
        $query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(":nombres", $nombres);
        $query->bindParam(":apellidos", $apellidos);
        $query->bindParam(":pro", $pro);
        $query->execute();
    }
    }
    echo "correcto";
    
}else{
    echo "ingrese nombre";
}
```

Resultado

**REGISTRO 01**

juan | carlos | H1,H2,H4

**REGISTRO 02**

Pedro | Flores | H1,H2,H4

Cuando guardo los registros estos se repiten en las dos filas, lo que busco es que cada registro se guarde con los checkbox seleccionados.

**Resultado deseado**

**REGISTRO 01**

juan | carlos | H1,H2,H4

**REGISTRO 02**

Pedro | Flores | H2,H3

Gracias por sus ayudas.

Comment: Depura los datos con un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. No sé si será porque no usas el índice `$i` al crear la variable `$pro`. Viendo el contenido podremos decirte.

Comment: Hola @a-cedano me sale este resultado

array(3) { ["nombres"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "juan" [1]=> string(5) "Percy" } ["apellidos"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "flores" [1]=> string(7) "Ferrari" } ["pro"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "H1" [1]=> string(2) "H2" [2]=> string(2) "H3" [3]=> string(2) "H4" } }

Comment: Según esos datos, `pro` es un array que tiene cuatro valores: `H1, H2, H3, H4`. Al hacer `implode` sin más estarás efectivamente insertando en cada fila los mismos valores. Si es posible lo mejor será organizar tus datos en el origen... ¿Qué valores de `pro` corresponden a cada `nombre`?

Comment: Si, es un formulario que se puede crear dos clientes y cada cliente se le puede agregar varios valores a traves de checkbox que son (H1,H2,H3,H4).

en la base de datos deberia figurar:
Juan | carlos | H1, H4
Pedro | Fuentes | H2, H3

Dependiendo de los checkbox seleccionados

Gracias por su respuesta

Comment: Ya, pero de la forma en que lo estás organizando no es tan fácil de determinar a quién corresponde cada valor. Solamente si existiera una regla que diga que a cada uno le corresponden **dos valores**, y aún así sería bastante precario, porque el usuario puede chequear más de cuatro checkboxes en total por ejemplo. En estos casos es mejor escribir tu formulario de modo que los datos vengan ya organizados de una forma segura, o sea, algo así: `array (array('nombres'=>'Juan', 'apellidos'=>'flores', 'pro'=>'H1,H2'),array('nombres'=>'Percy', 'apellidos'=>'Ferrari', 'pro'=>'H3,H4'));`  ...

Comment: Ahí tú tendrías una estructura segura, un array con varios arryas interiores donde cada uno tiene sus propios datos. Eso de generar datos mezclados es harto complicado y sujeto a errores varios. La forma de lectura (con un `foreach`) sería también más simple.